# How to change color of an agent in DES model

Tags: anylogic

I'm using 8.7.11 Professional. I seem to remember there was a way to change the color of an agent moving through a DES model dynamically by overlaying an identical 3d object, except for its color, and toggling a `.setVisible(boolean)` method in the Main DES model.

In my example I have 2 spheres ("sphere" & "sphere1") agent named "Ball". "sphere" has "MA_material_27" property set to cyan, the other's is red.

In Main, I'm trying to call the `.setVisible(boolean)` method in the "On exit:" of a delay block, but keep getting a "Cannot resolve" error.

I also seem to remember there was an example model where a opened box shot over a conveyor belt gap and then it showed as closed to demonstrate this animation functionality, but I can't find that example model either.

Comment: Can you share the full code

Comment: In the "On exit:" box of a Delay block I have `sphere.setVisible(false);` `sphere1.setVisible(true);`

Comment: Do you havent `agent.` before what you sent?

Comment: I didn't have agent. That fixed my issue. Also, the example model I was looking for was called "Changing Agent Shape".